# How can i send a request to php xml_rpc server using ajax

Tags: php, javascript, cordova, xml-rpc

I need to send xml_rpc request to my xml_rpc php server from phonegap app. Want to send request to server using ajax. Request must include, method, parameters and all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved !
Use Rest Controller, find the tutorial below

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2/